# debug grails integration tests in spring STS

Tags: grails

Does anybody know if there is a way to debug integration tets using the built in functionality of Spring STS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an open issue....
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-551

but there appears to be a work around
http://www.pubbs.net/201003/grails/8778-re-grails-user-how-to-debug-in-sts.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you meant, but you can right click on your test file in the project explorer and then select Debug As -> Grails Command (test-app). This will load grails and run your test in debug mode.

What I haven't figured out is how to re-run the test through the JUnit view, once the test has been run once. It keeps throwing a warning saying that tests must be run in debug mode and that I need to have "Keep Junit running" in the launch configuration. There is no such setting for integration tests and I suspect that it might be because the framework gets reloaded on every test run.